# Add class to parents that have children using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, parent, children

How would I go about adding a class only to the `li` parent that has children?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">parent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">parent</a>
    <ul>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: The html is malformed as hell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('li > *').parent().addClass(...);
```

or

```
$('li').has('*').addClass(...);
```

The first version may be marginally faster if you do:

```
$('li > :first-child').parent().addClass(...);
```

...hard to say though without testing.

All of these use fully valid CSS selectors.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs - Seems as though `$('li > *').parent().addClass(...);` is the fastest way that is currently an answer to this question.

Comment: @Jasper: Thanks for the test. Yeah, the native selectors are usually tough to beat. I'm a little surprised that `.has('*')` was so slow.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li:has(ul)').addClass('test-class');
```

I love how simple jQuery makes some things.

Here is jsfiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/p9M73/

Here is the documentation for `:has()`: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response :)

Comment: @IrvBriscoe You're welcome, I setup a jsperf to show the performance of the answers on this page: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs